# Does the smaller h always make the Runge-Kutta method error smaller on two-body problem? (python program attached)

Tags: numerical-methods, python, runge-kutta-methods

I want to solve a two-body problem using RK2. The following is a system of equations to be solved
\begin{equation}\label{two-body}
x^{\prime \prime}=-\frac{x}{r^{3}}, y^{\prime \prime}=-\frac{y}{r^{3}}, r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}
\end{equation}

let
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
v_{1}=x \\
v_{2}=y \\
v_{3}=x^{\prime} \\
v_{4}=y^{\prime} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
So we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
v_{1}^{\prime}=v_{3} \\
v_{2}^{\prime}=v_{4} \\
v_{3}^{\prime}=-\frac{v_{1}}{r^{3}} \\
v_{4}^{\prime}=-\frac{v_{2}}{r^{3}}
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}
Then let $\textbf{v}=\left[v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\right]=\left[x, y, x^{\prime}, y^{\prime}\right]$ and $f(t, v)=v^{\prime}(t)=\left[x^{\prime}, y^{\prime},-\frac{x}{r^{3}},-\frac{y}{r^{3}}\right], r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$.

Next, I arrange IVP like this
\begin{equation}\label{MSA two body}
\begin{aligned}
\textbf{v}^{\prime}(t)=f(t, \textbf{v})\\ 
\textbf{v}\left(t_{0}\right)=\textbf{v}_{0}.
\end{aligned}    
\end{equation}

Now, I want to solve with RK2

$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{v}_{n+1}=& \mathbf{v}_{n}+h\left(b_{1} k_{1}+b_{2} k_{2}\right) \\
k_{1}=& f\left(t_{n}, \mathbf{v}_{n}\right)=\left[x_{n}^{\prime}, y_{n}^{\prime}, x_{n}^{\prime \prime}, y_{n}^{\prime \prime}\right] \\
k_{2}=& f\left(t_{n}+a_{21} h_{1}, \mathbf{v}_{n}+a_{21} h k_{1}\right) \\
=& {\left[x_{n}^{\prime}+a_{21} h\left(\frac{-x_{n}}{\left(x_{n}^{2}+y_{n}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right), y_{n}^{\prime}+a_{21} h\left(\frac{-y_{n}}{\left(x_{n}^{2}+y_{n}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right),\right.} \\
&\left.\frac{-\left(x_{n}+a_{21} h x_{n}^{\prime}\right)}{\left(\left(x_{n}+a_{21} h x_{n}^{\prime}\right)^{2}+\left(y_{n}+a_{21} h y_{n}^{\prime}\right)^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}, \frac{-\left(y_{n}+a_{21} h y_{n}^{\prime}\right)}{\left(\left(x_{n}+a_{21} h x_{n}^{\prime}\right)^{2}+\left(y_{n}+a_{21} h y_{n}^{\prime}\right)^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right] \\
=& {\left[k_{1 x}+a_{21} h k_{1 x^{\prime}}, k_{1 y}+a_{21} h k_{1 y^{\prime}},\right.} \\
&\left.f_{x^{\prime}}\left(x_{n}+a_{21} h k_{1 x}, y+a_{21} h k_{1 y}\right), f_{y^{\prime}}\left(x_{n}+a_{21} h k_{1 x}, y_{n}+a_{21} h k_{1 y}\right)\right] .
\end{aligned}
$

with $k_{1 x}= x_{n}, k_{1 y}= y_{n}, k_{1 x^{\prime}}= \frac{-x_{n}}{\left(x_{n}^{2}+y_{n}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}, k_{1 y^{\prime}}= \frac{-y_{n}}{\left(x_{n}^{2}+y_{n}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ and $f_{x^{\prime}}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)= \frac{-x_{n}}{\left(x_{n}^{2}+y_{n}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}},f_{y^{\prime}}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)= \frac{-y_{n}}{\left(x_{n}^{2}+y_{n}^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.

Now, I will compute analytics and numeric value (with RK2 there are Heun, Ralston,midpoint and new method with unusual RK2 coefficient) from two-body problem then compare the error. Here the program
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1P0aRbqmFa1b77mGtzsojmZwe3BThzf_D?usp=sharing
And I got plot like this
[image]

The question is how can when h decreasing the error gets bigger in all methods after N>600? (N is number of point on interval)

Comment: You need to edit your very last sentence as it does not make grammatical sense. You have not defined any variable called $ay$ either.

It appears to me that you are feeling the effect of rounding error. If the time interval is constant and $N$ is the number of subdivisions (you haven't defined $N$), then I expect the error to increase as you increase $N$ even further.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped and now fixed. @CarlChristian

Comment: You are almost certainly feeling the effect of rounding errors. I expect that you will get erratic curves as you increase $N$ further. I don't know how Baru's method is defined, but it appears to be have 2nd order like the other. I think you will find it interesting to repeat the experiment with methods of different order.

Comment: Thanks! You're correct. It's because of because of rounding errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two conceptual errors in the code

- you start every method step from the exact solution. However, to explore the global error of the methods, you need to continue from the numerical values so that the errors can accumulate.
- when you compute the $L^2$ norm of the error, then you need to multiply the square sum by $h$, and return the square root of that, $\|f\|_{L^2}\simeq \sqrt{\sum |f(x_k)|^2\Delta x}$.

In the second point the effects of the first point will distort the picture somewhat. The global error is (weakly) proportional to the unit step error. The single-step error that you compute is $h$ times the unit step error. Thus in the square sum you get a factor $h$ too many.

---

But in the main it is as said in the comments, the global error behaves similar to $\frac{\mu}{h}+h^2$, $\mu$ the general error per floating point operation, accumulated over $n\sim \frac1h$ steps, and the method step error $\sim h^3$ similarly accumulated to a global error proportional to $h^2$. This gives the typical hook shape with the apex around $h=10^{-5}$ for 64bit double precision.